# Macports selfupdate "Error: updating PortIndex" after moving local Portfile

Tags: macports

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

Yields:

```
Error: updating PortIndex for file:///Users/jonny/Projects/Active/macports/ failed
```

I know exactly why, because that directory has been moved. However, there is no indication of how macports is still looking in the wrong place.

I've tried going to the new location and typing

```
sudo portindex -f
```

To re-index but alas, no luck. I want macports to forget that old directory and move on. It's too clingy.

Answer (score 1):

I simply had to edit my `sources.conf` and remove the stale reference.

```
sudo nano /opt/local/etc/macports/sources.conf
```